# Daily add rows and delete rows according to date in PostgesSQL

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

- Database system: Postgres
- TypeORM version: 0.2.24

**TLDR**

As clear from the title I am making a game room app, Using NodeJS and TypeORM for the backend.

Some preface:

- Multiple shops
- A shop runs on multiple dates and has multiple SEATS
- You can book say in advance 2 weeks

My current "solution":

- An array of 5-minute long time slots containing number SEATS occupied
- If the shop opens for 2 hrs
- [ 0, 1, 5, 1, ...24 elements]
- Where index I is the Ith 5minute of the day

```
| ID | DATE     | SHOP | filledSeats                   |
|----|----------|------|-------------------------------|
|  1 | 5/5/2020 | 21   | [ 0, 1, 5, 1, ...24 elements] |
```

```
@Entity("occupancies")
export class Occupancy extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Column()
    date: Date;

    @ManyToOne(()=>Shop, (shop: Shop) => shop.occupancies)
    shop: Shop;

    @Column({array: true})
    filled: number[];
}
```

I want to automatically delete yesterday's entries and add rows for 2 weeks later. How can I do that? Also, feel free to suggest other approaches for the problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question needs to be improved a bit to get some help: what do you mean with `automatically`? You need to do it every day? Cron jobs could be used for that, it depends on the underlying infrastructure. You need to do it when a certain event happens and need help to build a query to obtain that result? It's feasible if more context is provided. It's hard to tell for now.

Comment: Thanks for help!! I have updated the title. I want to do it daily. I will now search about Cron jobs thanks again. I didn't really knew what to search.